# ContourPlot and Colorfunction

Tags: plotting

I have the following code:

```
ContourPlot[
(2.7` (-3.8099999999999996` + 7.24` x - 3.24` x^2 + 3.62` y - 6.48` x y + 6.48` x^2 y))/
( 11.43` - 6.48` x + 3.24` x^2 - 3.24` y + 6.48` x y) - 
( 3 (-(-1 + x)^2 + (1 + 2 (-1 + x) x) y))/( 3 + (-2 + x) x + (-1 + 2 x) y) , 
{x, 0.5, 1}, {y, 0, 0.5},
 ContourStyle -> {Black, Thick}, Contours -> {0}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
(If[#1 > 0, Directive[Lighter[Lighter[Lighter[Yellow]]]], White] &)]
```

which gives me

[image]

But my color function should color the area above the black line white while color area below the black line yellow.

However, if I use the colorfunction `Rainbow`, then it will give me the correct coloring result:

[image]

What should I do to make my 1st color function behave as expected?

Comment: Your code gives what you expected when I run it on V9.0.1 on OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: It also works as expected on V8.0.4 on OS X 10.7.5. What platform is your problem arising on?

Comment: weird... mine is V9.0.1 on OS X 10.8.4

Comment: @m_goldberg,@Jens, please try the updated code. Something was lost in the earlier code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always forget about `ColorFunctionScaling` too:

```
ContourPlot[(2.7` (-3.8099999999999996` + 7.24` x - 3.24` x^2 + 3.62` y - 6.48` x y + 
            6.48` x^2 y))/(11.43` - 6.48` x + 3.24` x^2 - 3.24` y + 6.48` x y) - (
            3 (-(-1 + x)^2 + (1 + 2 (-1 + x) x) y))/(3 + (-2 + x) x + (-1 + 2 x) y),
            {x, 0.5, 1}, {y, 0, 0.5}, 
    ContourStyle -> {Black, Thick}, Contours -> {0}, 
    ColorFunction -> (If[#1>0, Directive[Lighter[Lighter[Lighter[Yellow]]]], White] &), 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 You were a little faster than me, it seems...

Answer (score 5):

The argument to the `ColorFunction` shouldn't be scaled, because if it is then the zero passed to the `ColorFunction` depends on whether the minimum and maximum of the plot values are symmetric with respect to zero or not.

So we have to add the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` to the `ContourPlot` as follows:

```
ContourPlot[(2.7` (-3.8099999999999996` + 7.24` x - 3.24` x^2 + 
       3.62` y - 6.48` x y + 6.48` x^2 y))/(11.43` - 6.48` x + 
     3.24` x^2 - 3.24` y + 
     6.48` x y) - (3 (-(-1 + x)^2 + (1 + 2 (-1 + x) x) y))/(3 + (-2 + 
        x) x + (-1 + 2 x) y), {x, 0.5, 1}, {y, 0, 0.5}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Black, Thick}, Contours -> {0}, 
 ColorFunction -> (If[#1 > 0, 
     Directive[Lighter[Lighter[Lighter[Yellow]]]], White] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

This produces the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

This is more of very long comment than an answer, but I hope it cast more murk on the problem.

If I evaluate

```
ContourPlot[
  (2.7` (-3.8099999999999996` + 7.24` x - 3.24` x^2 + 3.62` y - 6.48` x y + 6.48` x^2 y))/
    (11.43` - 6.48` x + 3.24` x^2 - 3.24` y + 6.48` x y) - 
    (3 (-(-1 + x)^2 + (1 + 2 (-1 + x) x) y))/(3 + (-2 + x) x + (-1 + 2 x) y),
  {x, 0.5, 1}, {y, 0, 0.5}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Black, Thick}, 
  Contours -> {0}, 
  ColorFunction -> (If[#1 > 0, Directive[Lighter[Lighter[Lighter[Yellow]]]], White] &)]
```

I get[image]

all.yellow.png

However, If I change -3.8099999999999996` to -3.81` and only that and then evaluate

```
ContourPlot[
  (2.7` (-3.81` + 7.24` x - 3.24` x^2 + 3.62` y - 6.48` x y + 6.48` x^2 y))/
    (11.43` - 6.48` x + 3.24` x^2 - 3.24` y + 6.48` x y) - 
    (3 (-(-1 + x)^2 + (1 + 2 (-1 + x) x) y))/(3 + (-2 + x) x + (-1 + 2 x) y),
  {x, 0.5, 1}, {y, 0, 0.5}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Black, Thick}, 
  Contours -> {0}, 
  ColorFunction -> (If[#1 > 0, Directive[Lighter[Lighter[Lighter[Yellow]]]], White] &)]
```

I get

[image: yellow.white.png]

So both of the previously posted answers may be right, but they don't seem to tell the whole story.

Comment: Nice observation. What leads to this difference?

Comment: @wdg. I'd like to know the answer to that myself. It seems very strange behavior on the part of _Mathematica_.

Comment: I tried to compare evaluation trace but my laptop response was an attempt to fly away. Interesting observation :) +1.