# ColorFunction on a surface

Tags: plotting, color

I have a surface in 3D space which is defined by equation in `ContourPlot3D`. For simplicity let me use x + y == z surface (in reality I have a transcendental equation). I also have function of the variables (x,y,z) which behaviour I need to study on the surface. I want to show function's values by color, but it's fails even in such simple example:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := z^2
ContourPlot3D[x + y == z, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[f[x, y, z]]],AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Here levels z and -z must be the same color because I use the even function z^2. What did I missed? Thanks!

Comment: "What did I miss?" - trying the option `ColorFunctionScaling`.

Comment: That's quite often the case. I'd close it as a duplicate of [ContourPlot and Colorfunction](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28647/5478)